# Is there a way to check if a specific snap is running (from the CLI)?

Tags: command-line, snap, process

Let's say I've launched the Nextcloud Client, but I haven't seen the icon show up in the panel (Gnome Shell is finicky that way). How do I check to see if it is running (from the CLI)?

Is there a one-shot command for this?

> (Please do not suggest using the system monitor, I know you can do
> that. But it requires that you check the properties of the running
> process to determine if it is a snap or not).

---

> `snap info` and `snap services` are not options for GUI programs, as they only tell you
> about services (for instance: wekan, or nextcloud-server).

Comment: What if you have *full command line* enabled in system monitor? Then I guess it would be easier from the full path to determine if it's running.

Comment: @pomsky I'd forgotten that. I still hope there's a way to check from the CLI, however.

Answer (score 2):

Command `snap services` will give you the list of services, you can try

```
snap services | grep active
```

Comment: This only covers snaps which provide services, not gui programs.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo snap info "name of snap"` it should give the details of the snap and the services it's running.

Comment: The issue with this command is that it only tells you if *daemons* are running, not if say, a GUI tool is running. I'll edit my question to mention this.

Comment: Not too sure then to be honest. Just thinking about it another way, if it's the client could you not use a script to create a test file in the folder that is syncing via the client then test for its existence on the nextcloud server using webdav? Then you'd know it's running as its uploaded the test file.

Comment: I already know how to check via that method, but I want a general solution for any snap that works in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command :

> snap changes

Find status Doing ... (check the ID)

Run command

> snap watch ID (ID of doing status)